# Jaxb2Marshaller with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, web-services, marshalling, spring-integration, jaxb2

I am creating a spring integration outbound gateway with the next configuration:

- Direct channels for invocationChannel and responseChannel
- One request transformer with the following configuration (updated on update II)
- Web service gateway configuration:

---

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "invocationChannel")
public MessageHandler wsOutboundGateway() throws Exception {

    MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gw =
            new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(
                    "http://localhost:8098/mockPort", 
                    jaxb2Marshaller());
    gw.setOutputChannelName("responseChannel");
    return gw;
}

public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() throws Exception {

    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setProcessExternalEntities(true);
    // List of packages with XML Root elements (types) generated with Wsdl2Java 
    marshaller.setContextPaths(
            "com.company.wsdl.types.p1", "com.company.wsdl.types.p2");

}
```

But I am getting: "Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized" and I hae any idea about this error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPVersionMismatchException: Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:150)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory.createEnvelope(EnvelopeFactory.java:110)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:68)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:128)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:189)
```

**UPDATE**

I changed my RequestType to the Envelope one and it seems to be recognized but now I am getting: "org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Internal Server Error [500]".

My server is listening via SOAP UI and it is accessible in the browser.

**UPDATE II**

Transformer and Handler configuration:

---

```
SENDER

@Transformer(inputChannel="requestChannel", outputChannel="invocationChannel")
public ResquestType buildRequest(Message<String> msg) {
//creates a ResquestType from msg param
return ResquestType;
}

RESPONSE HANDLER

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="responseChannel")
public int getResponse(Message<Envelope> msg) {
// Builds the response status
}
```

---

I am sending the structure:

- RequestType
- Envelope
- Header
- Body

Receiving structure:

- Envelope
- Header
- Body
- ResponseType

Comment: Show, please, the expception on the server side. And share your entity which you send over that `wsOutboundGateway` with `marshaller`

Comment: There is no exception on the server side. I am looking at SOAP UI log. I am edited my question in order to clarify the SOAP structure. The server reply the expected response.

Comment: If you have `Internal Server Error [500]` there should be something else like StackTrace to determine an issue... Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: That is my fault Artem, sorry. I returned to the previous configuration (the current configuration on the post) and my error is "Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized" instead Error 500

Comment: Good. That's why I asked you to show that JaxB model

Comment: Any idea about "Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized"? I suppose the problem is in the response parsing but I am not sure how to debug this kind of error.

Comment: Since you use SOAP UI, there is a tool to monitor request/response to figure out if you send/receive correct XML for request and response.

Comment: After a quick debugging with SOAP UI, I've detected that the problem was an error on the Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshalling method. I was expecting Envelope but another type is on my own response schema. Wasted time just debugging with eclipse!. Now is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66494/discussion-between-prm-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Yes, you can secure it with sertificate, but it will be another SO question. However you can just go ahead with Spring WS abilities and add `SecurityInterceptor` to the `MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Internal Server Error [500]: Unable to create envelope from given source because the namespace was not recognized

SOAP UI has a feature to trace request/response. Using that you can take a look where you or your service provide bad XML for SOAP.